# SQL Query not returning results

Tags: sql, filter

I am using three categories of checkboxes to filter posts from WordPress (this question is about the query), and I know for a fact I should be returning results with the following query (I generate the line 7 automatically based on what's selected in my filter):

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON(wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id) 
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON(wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) 
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON(wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id) 
LEFT JOIN wp_terms ON(wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id) 
WHERE 
    wp_terms.slug IN ('academia') AND wp_terms.slug IN ('early-career') 
    AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'jobtype' 
    AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' 
    AND wp_posts.post_type = 'jobs' 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

I have at least 5 posts that have are in the category `academia` AND `early-career`.

If I change line 7 to just have one `IN` statement, it filters that one category just fine:

```
wp_terms.slug IN ('academia','journalism') //More than one from same category
AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'jobtype'......
```

It'll find all jobs that are either academia OR journalism (exactly what I expect), but when I add in the other `IN` statement, nothing is returned (even though I have posts that match the logic).

Can anyone tell me if something is wrong (maybe the spaces between the `IN` and the values?), because I've been at this for days with no luck.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

**P.S.** If anyone wants to take a look at the site this is on (for looking at what I mean): http://www.libertyguide.com/jobs

Currently I have a global `OR` instead of any `IN`'s until I get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying multiple values in the `IN` clause states the row must match ONE of those values. Specifying 2 `IN` clauses states that the row must match BOTH, which is impossible (a varchar cannot be both 'academia' and 'early-career' at the same time).

Try adding the following to the end of your query:

```
HAVING COUNT(*) > [NUMBER OF VALUES SELECTED]
```

So it becomes:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON(wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id) 
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON(wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) 
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON(wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id) 
LEFT JOIN wp_terms ON(wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id) 
WHERE 
    wp_terms.slug IN ('academia', 'early-career') 
    AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'jobtype' 
    AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' 
    AND wp_posts.post_type = 'jobs' 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Comment: This is more scalable, but I would point out that it only works if the values are unique so that it can't have the same value twice

Comment: I think this would work if only one thing was selected in each category.  If I have HAVING COUNT(*) > 2 but query for 'academia,'journalism', and 'early-career', couldn't it return posts with 'academia' AND 'journalism, but NOT 'early-career'?

Comment: @Kevin: Yes that is correct, but I suspect that WordPress doesn't allow that to happen.

Comment: @JoshAllen. You are correct, but as I've stated the number in the HAVING clause should match the number of categories selected. If you select 3 categories the clause will be 'HAVING COUNT(*) = 3'.

Comment: @weenoid If you go to the site that I mention, I have three different 'categories' with multiple actual categories inside it.  If I select two from the first 'category' and one from the third, I want it to return results if it's either from the first category AND has the third (or AT least one of the third if more than one is selected). I think this would be great if I have a need for single-level filtering.  In that case, this would be great.  Definitely bookmarked for future projects.

Comment: @weenoid because in the case you have here, I might as well just make it a global `AND` search because if that's the case, it's making sure that you have everything that you've selected.  However, I want it to be more of a mix between `OR` and `AND`.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON(wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id) 
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON(wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) 
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON(wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id) 
LEFT JOIN wp_terms wt1 ON(wt1.term_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id) 
LEFT JOIN wp_terms wt2 ON(wt2.term_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id) 
WHERE 
   wt1.slug = 'academia' AND wt2.slug = 'early-career' 
    AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'jobtype' 
    AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' 
    AND wp_posts.post_type = 'jobs' 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

**EDIT**
To support N categories, you could try this:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON(wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id) 
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON(wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) 
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON(wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id) 
WHERE 
    wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'jobtype' 
    AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' 
    AND wp_posts.post_type = 'jobs' 
    AND wp_term_taxonomy.term_id IN (SELECT term_id from wp_terms where slug = 'academia')
    AND wp_term_taxonomy.term_id IN (SELECT term_id from wp_terms where slug = 'early-career')
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

And you could add the AND wp_term_taxonomy... lines as many times as you need to in code.

Comment: This will work, but doesn't scale well when larger numbers of categories are selected.

Comment: I like the looks of this one, but I don't think it would filter exactly how I want.  I want to do an OR filter inside categories, but an AND filter across categories.  For example, I want it to look something like this: WHERE ('academia' OR 'journalism') AND ('this' OR 'that') AND ('something' OR 'something-else').  Would this work with it?

Comment: Would I alter it something like this for more than one per category?:  `(SELECT term_id from wp_terms where slug = 'academia' OR 'journalism')`?

Comment: @therealmitchconnors: Your updated query scales even less, now you need to add in an extra query for every category specified.

Comment: Yes, this query can support your AND/OR requirements (though I would like to see the UI for that!).  Simply replace `WHERE slug = ''` to `WHERE slug IN ('','')` with the OR set in the parenthesis.