# How to perform a WHERE similar to "NOT IN" with a list of value coming from a HTTP FORM?

Tags: sql, sql-server, forms

I have web application developed in C#, where a page is showing the output of a SQL query; the query is a linq call to a store procedure and I am using SQL Server 2008.

One of the column display the tags associated with the result line; on the same page a list of check-boxes is displayed, each check-box correspond to a tag, and if the user turn on or off one or multiple check-box I want to filter the query.

My simplest SQL solution would be to us "NOT IN" like the following:

```
select * from [mytable] where [tags] not in ('tag1','tag2, etc...)
```

Given I convert the FORM POST to a string with comma separated values.
Example:

```
string tags = ParseFormAndConvertCheckBoxToCSV(Page.Request.Form);
string sqlcmd = "select * from [mytable] where [tags] not in (" + tags + ")";
```

But I don't want to dynamically build the SQL because as far as I know [that would be bad](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html).

I can imagine few way of [splitting the string with comma separated list of values in SQL nd store the values into a in-memory table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878833/passing-a-varchar-full-of-comma-delimited-values-to-a-sql-server-in-function):

```
declare @tagscsv nvarchar(MAX)
declare @notags TABLE(Value nvarchar(50))

set @tagscsv = 'taxi,ivf'

Declare @x XML 
select @x = cast('<A>'+ replace(@tagscsv,',','</A><A>')+ '</A>' as xml)

insert into @notags
select t.value('.', 'nvarchar(50)') as v from @x.nodes('/A') as x(t)

select * from [mytable] where [tags] not in (select * from @notags)
```

...but this too sounds like a dirty trick.

To me it looks like this should be a very common situation, and I figure out a lot of people out there faced this problem in the past, but searching on google I could not find an elegant solution.

Anyone can help?

Comment: tags ='A' OR tags='B' etc., is that what you are looking for?

Comment: What do you mean by `I don't want to dynamically build the SQL because that would be bad.` ??

Comment: Try my solution [at this question][1].  You are right, this is a very common question.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10355507/sql-query-not-returning-results/10355594#10355594

Comment: Please provide additional context.  Are you using string SQL queries, linq to sql, something else?  What platform is the webpage built on (ASP, APSX, MVC, PHP, something else)?  Also, what makes a split comma separated list a dirty trick?

Comment: I edited the question to provide more context, yes I am using C#, linq to entities, and a store procedure for SQL server 2008; but I have the feeling my question is of a general nature and would apply to other programming frameworks and databases as well.

Comment: I have updated my answer.  If you have to use a Stored Procedure then your answer is good (though I would use a loop rather then build an XML tree).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**:  Missed the stored procedure part.
With stored procedures you do not have a lot of options.  I usually do what you did, split the comma seperated string and save the values to a temp table (or table variable).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SplitAndStuff
    @List nvarchar(MAX) = NULL,
    @SplitOn nvarchar(5) = ','  --This can be replaced with a literal if it is always a comma.
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Pos int;
    DECLARE @SplitOnLength int;
    DECLARE @Results TABLE (value nvarchar(MAX))
    SET @SplitOnLength = DATALENGTH(@SplitOn) / 2;

    IF (RIGHT(@List, @SplitOnLength) <> @SplitOn) SET @List = @List + @SplitOn; --Add trailling split string if there is not one already.

    SET @Pos = CHARINDEX(@SplitOn, @List, 1)                                    --Initalize for loop.  (The starting position returned is 1-based, not 0-based.)

    WHILE @Pos > 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @Results (value) SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(@List,1,@Pos-1)AS int);

        SET @List = SUBSTRING(@List, @Pos+@SplitOnLength, DATALENGTH(@List) / 2);
        SET @Pos = CHARINDEX(@SplitOn, @List, 1);
    END
END
GO
```

If your stored procedure is not doing anything else (besides the look up) you could use my original LINQ answer below:

Since you are using LINQ you need to split `tagscsv` and use the resulting array to perform an "where in" query:

```
string[] tags = tagscsv.Split(',');
var output = from q in db.Table where !tags.Contains(q) select q;
```

See also:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132407.aspx
- [Using LINQ to Perform "WHERE IN (Value1,Value2)" Queries](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2008/05/09/using-linq-to-perform-quot-where-in-value1-value2-quot-queries.aspx)
- [The NOT IN clause in LINQ to SQL](http://introducinglinq.com/blogs/marcorusso/archive/2008/01/14/the-not-in-clause-in-linq-to-sql.aspx)

Comment: To split the string I think the solution I found using xml is faster than a loop, in terms of pure performance.

Comment: @Max Favilli You would have to test it to be sure, but conceptually you have to go through the string once to replace the commas with tags, then again to parse the XML, then you are looping through each element in the XML.  Of course you could enhance my loop (which I did quickly the other day) to not change List and to just track the starting and ending points of the substrings which would result in only 1 pass through (2 if you count the search for the next comma) of the whole string.  Also remember that XML has additional overhead to build and maintain the tree.